# jQuery slide closed when leaving open element in accordion menu

Tags: jquery, accordion

Ok so I have the following code to have an "accordion" like effect on some items on a web page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cont-wrap').hide();
  $('.cont').on('mouseenter', '.cont-title', function(){
    $(this).next().slideDown(300).siblings('.cont-wrap').slideUp(300);
  });
  $('.main').on('mouseleave', '.cont-wrap, cont-title', function(){
    $(this('.cont-wrap')).slideUp(300);
  });
});
```

What I am trying to accomplish with the mouseleave section is all the cont-wrap sections returning to a hidden state when the mouse leaves the main div, thereby resetting the section of the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$(this('.cont-wrap')).slideUp(300);` .. what you are trying here

Comment: i actually just figure a better way to do it like so

Comment: $('.main').on('mouseleave', '.cont', function(){
     $('.cont-wrap').slideUp(300);
    });

Comment: You need to say what is going wrong, not just ask SO to do your work for you.

Comment: Well I was actually wondering why it wasn't working but I figured it out anyway

Answer (score 0):

Get this figured out yet?

```js
$('.cont-wrap').hide();
$('.cont').on('mouseenter', '.cont-title', function() {
  $('.cont').not($(this).parent()).addClass('minimize');
  $(this).parent().addClass('maximize');
  $(this).next().slideDown(300).siblings('.cont-wrap').slideUp(300);
})
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.cont', function() {
  $('.cont-wrap').slideUp(300);
})
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.cont-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 1);
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 10%, 1);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 0.1); 
  border-width: 1px 0;
}
.cont-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.cont.maximize {
  flex: 2;
}
.cont.minimize {
  flex: 1;
}
.cont.maximize .cont-title {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.cont.maximize .cont-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="cont-title">Pirate Ipsum</div>
  <div class="cont-wrap">Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="cont-title">Pirate Ipsum</div>
  <div class="cont-wrap">Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="cont-title">Pirate Ipsum</div>
  <div class="cont-wrap">Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="cont-title">Pirate Ipsum</div>
  <div class="cont-wrap">Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="cont-title">Pirate Ipsum</div>
  <div class="cont-wrap">Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="cont-title">Pirate Ipsum</div>
  <div class="cont-wrap">Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/ew8bysy8/